# Derive of integral and integral of derive

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I confuse about this

$$ \frac{d}{dt} \int_0^t f(s) ds = f(t)  \quad or =f(t)-f(0)  ?$$
and
$$ \int_0^t \frac{d}{ds} f(s)ds = f(t)-f(0) \quad  or = f(t) $$

with explanations please.

Comment: Are you familiar with the fundamental theorems of calculus? All the answers you seek (in this question :-) )derive from them.

Comment: Yes i do, but  when we read Lebesgue's theory, we get some questions.I need just some explanations and how did we get this or what's the origine ?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the antiderivative of $f(x)=F(x)$ and the derivative of $f(x)=f'(x)$.

Then $\dfrac{d}{dt}\int_0^tf(s)ds=\dfrac{d}{dt}[F(t)-F(0)]=f(t)$ since $F(0)$ is a constant.

$\int_0^t\dfrac{d}{ds}f(s)ds=\int_0^tf'(s)ds=f(t)-f(0)$

This of course is derived from the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Comment: Thanks Olivia, really clear, because when we use Lebesque theorem one can say derive of integral is the integral of derive

Answer (score 0):

This is from the fundamental theorem of Calculus as stated above. That being said there exist functions such as [Volterra's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra%27s_function) that have the properties

> V is differentiable everywhere,
>   The derivative V ′ is bounded everywhere,
>   The derivative is not Riemann-integrable.